# Send unserialized & unescaped HTML file data to an API with a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, html-parsing

I wanted to create a bash script that takes an HTML file and sends it to several APIs.

I have a `test.html` file with unserialized HTML data like this:

```html
<h2 id="overview">Overview</h2>
<p>Have the source of truth in your own space at <strong>somewhere</strong></p>
<pre>
<code class="lang-javascript">function go() {
  console.log(&#39;code blocks can be a pain&#39;);
}
go();
</code>
</pre>
```

I need to send the content of the file somehow to an API, like this:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://devo.to/api/articles' \
--header 'api-key: askldjfalefjw02ijef02eifj20' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "article": {
    "title": "Blog Article",
    "body_markdown": "@test.html",
  }
}'
```

The only way I can think of so far, is to serialize/escape the HTML file, reading it into a variable as a string (like `$TEST_HTML=$(cat serialized_test.html`) and then passing it to `"body_markdown"`.

Would it be possible to serialize/escape the HTML in one step inside the bash script or is there maybe a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `jq` to build the JSON argument, and let it deal with properly escaping quotes, newlines and such in the included HTML file:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://devo.to/api/articles' \
--header 'api-key: askldjfalefjw02ijef02eifj20' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw "$(jq -n --arg html "$(< test.html)" '{article:{title:"Blog Article",body_markdown:$html}}')"
```

The `jq` invocation puts the contents of `test.html` in a string variable `$html`, and evaluates to:

```
    {
      "article": {
        "title": "Blog Article",
        "body_markdown": "<h2 id=\"overview\">Overview</h2>\n<p>Have the source of truth in your own space at <strong>somewhere</strong></p>\n<pre>\n<code class=\"lang-javascript\">function go() {\n  console.log(&#39;code blocks can be a pain&#39;);\n}\ngo();\n</code>\n</pre>"
      }
    }
```

---

`$(< filename)` is a `bash` substitution that evaluates to the contents of the given file. It's to be preferred over `$(cat filename)` in `bash` as it doesn't involve running another process.