# Shell/cURL: $DATE is not interpreted but shows up as is

Tags: linux, shell, curl

In the following code/file, I am trying to get current date in the final email.

But what I am getting is the variable $DATE itself in the email.  Same for `$from_email` and `$to_email.`

My question: is there a different way/method than using `'` in `--data`?

Here's my code:

```
NL=$'\n'
DATE=$(date)
DATE=${DATE%$NL}
echo $DATE
#
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_CURL_API_KEY" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '\
{
        "personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "$to_email"}]}],\
        "from": {"email": "$from_email"},\
        "subject": "SendGrid API $DATE",\
        "content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Sent on $DATE using Shell/Curl"}]\
}\
'
```

Comment: Read up on the difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: (In cases like this, I'm a fan of using `jq` to build the json and passing variables to it)

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729928/9952196

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash for a more generic approach

Comment: @Shawn I tried to use the generic approach.

`--data '\
  { \
  "personalizations": [ {"to": [ {"email": ' "$to_email" '} ]} ], \
  "from": {"email": ' "$from_email" '}, \
  "subject": "SendGrid API ' "$DATE" ', \
  "content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Sent on ' "$DATE" ' using Shell/Curl"}] \
  }'`

But, with this, ,I am getting this error:

`{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">`

Comment: The `<HTML...` in the error shown above is from `gmail.com` web page!

Comment: Are you adding the needed double quotes around strings in the json? (One reason why I prefer the jq approach; much less error prone)